# How to distinguish between two JButtons with same name

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am developing a swing application where I need to have delete buttons. Each delete button clicked will eventually perform a deletion of a row from a different file depending on which button was clicked. The  problem is I cant not distinguish the two buttons by names as they both have same name as "Delete". I don't want to name them differently as I may have lot of such Delete buttons. is there another property like ID or something that I can assign them?

Comment: I am saving a key value pair to a file and creating a delete button for each of such a pair [name, value]. A created pair is shown in UI dynamically after creation and next to each pair a delete button is created to remove the pair from the file. Let's say there are two pairs with each having its own delete button. When a delete button is clicked i need to know which pair to remove form the file.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid use of "switchboard" listeners and instead give each JButton its own Action object, one created by overriding AbstractAction. the AbstractAction could even be objects of the same class, but that also has a reference to the file or String collection of interest, so that the delete action is performed on the correct item.

Another option is to associate the button with object that requires an action on it via a `HashMap<JButton, ActionableType>`.

Here are two examples combined into one program. The JPanel on the right contains rows of word pairs together with a delete JButton, the JButton is intimately tied to the JLabel containing word pairs, since they are all held in a common object, WordPairRow. There is a single ActionListener class that is added to every delete JButton, but which is passed the unique WordPairRow and the container JPanel that holds all the components:

```
wpRow.addDeleteListener(new DeleteAction(container, wpRow));
```

If any delete button is pressed, then that row of words and the button are removed from the container.

Perhaps a better solution is to display the word pairs within a JTable using a custom table model. In this model there's a 3rd column of booleans that is displayed as a check box. When the "Delete Checked Rows" JButton below the JTable is checked, all the checked rows are deleted from the JTable. Later when you want to extract the changed list, simply iterate through the table model extracting the words that are remaining.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class WordPairTest extends JPanel {
    private static final String DATA_FILE_NAME = "WordPair.txt";
    private JPanel wordListPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    private WordPairTableModel tableModel = new WordPairTableModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

    public WordPairTest(Scanner scanner) {
        int rowNumber = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            if (tokens.length == 2) {
                WordPairRow wpRow = new WordPairRow(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
                addRowToList(rowNumber, wordListPanel, wpRow);
                rowNumber++;

                tableModel.addRow(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
            }
        }

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new DeleteCheckedRowsAction(tableModel)));

        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        tablePanel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        tablePanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        add(wordListPanel);
        add(tablePanel);
    }

    private void addRowToList(int row, JPanel container, WordPairRow wpRow) {
        container.add(wpRow.getFirstWord(), createGbc(0, row));
        container.add(wpRow.getSecondWord(), createGbc(1, row));
        container.add(wpRow.getDeleteBtn(), createGbc(2, row));

        wpRow.addDeleteListener(new DeleteAction(container, wpRow));
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        return gbc;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        InputStream resource = WordPairTest.class
                .getResourceAsStream(DATA_FILE_NAME);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(resource);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("WordPairTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new WordPairTest(scanner));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

class WordPairRow {
    private JLabel firstWord = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel secondWord = new JLabel("");
    private JButton deleteBtn = new JButton("Delete");

    public WordPairRow(String word1, String word2) {
        firstWord.setText(word1);
        secondWord.setText(word2);
    }

    public JLabel getFirstWord() {
        return firstWord;
    }

    public JLabel getSecondWord() {
        return secondWord;
    }

    public JButton getDeleteBtn() {
        return deleteBtn;
    }

    public void addDeleteListener(ActionListener listener) {
        deleteBtn.addActionListener(listener);
    }
}

class DeleteAction implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel container;
    private WordPairRow wpRow;

    public DeleteAction(JPanel container, WordPairRow wpRow) {
        this.container = container;
        this.wpRow = wpRow;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        container.remove(wpRow.getFirstWord());
        container.remove(wpRow.getSecondWord());
        container.remove(wpRow.getDeleteBtn());
        container.revalidate();
        container.repaint();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class WordPairTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = { "First Word", "Second Word", "" };

    public WordPairTableModel() {
        super(COLUMNS, 0);
    }

    public void addRow(String word1, String word2) {
        Vector<Object> rowData = new Vector<>();
        rowData.add(word1);
        rowData.add(word2);
        rowData.add(Boolean.FALSE);
        super.addRow(rowData);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (getRowCount() > 0) {
            Object item = getValueAt(0, columnIndex);
            if (item != null) {
                return item.getClass();
            }
        }
        return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return column == 2;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DeleteCheckedRowsAction extends AbstractAction {
    private WordPairTableModel tableModel;

    public DeleteCheckedRowsAction(WordPairTableModel tableModel) {
        super("Delete Checked Rows");
        this.tableModel = tableModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int row = tableModel.getRowCount() - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
            Boolean check = (Boolean) tableModel.getValueAt(row, 2);
            if (check) {
                tableModel.removeRow(row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data file:

```
hello, goodbye
hola, adiós
shalom, shalom
bonjour, au revoir 
buongiorno, arrivederci 
hyvaa paivaa, nakemiin 
tere, nagemist 
kuei, niaut 
konnichiwa, sayonara 
privet, dosvidanya 
ahoj, cau
cześć, do widzenia
merhaba, elveda
hallo, vaarwel
saluton, adiaŭ
```

GUI appearance:

[image]

Comment: you brought up interesting approach that I can use somewhere else I need. Any how I found the solution and posting it.

Comment: @hhafeez: sorry, but yours seems a hacky solution one that would not scale well. If you post more specific information and code about the problem including exactly what you mean by deleting lines, etc, I think we can improve on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be solved by setting the ActionCommand for the button. By default if we don't set the ActionCommand then the name of the button is set as action command. I did the following :

```
JButton delete = new JButton("Delete");
 delete.setActionCommand("action1");'
```

then in  ActionListener, I can check if

```
event.getAactionCommand.equlas("action1")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a single actionListener, then just store the references to the buttons so the references are available in the action listener:

```
 JButton button1 = new JButton("Delete");
 JButton button2 = new JButton("Delete");
```

then in the action listener:

```
   Object src = event.getSource();
   if ( src == button1 ) {
      // perform the action for button1
   } else if ( scr ==  button2 ) {
     // perform the action for button2
   }
```

Comment: that still doesn't solve the problem. since button1 and button2 are created at run time every time user click on an Add button.